# Differentiability of multi-variable functions

Tags: derivatives

Is the following function differentiable at the origin:

$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^4y^6+x^3+xy^4}{x^2+y^4}$$

I think it is differentiable but I don't know how to prove it? Can I use partial derivatives?

Comment: How is $f$ defined at the origin?  Does a limit exist for $f$ as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$? If not, then, $f$ isn't even continuous there.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Fix $x=0$ and see what happens to the derivative as $y \to 0$, then fix $y=0$ and see what happens to the derivative as $x \to 0$.

They should disagree, hence the function is not differentiable at $(0,0)$

Comment: both of them give zero!

Comment: @user160492 not exactly. Note that $f(0,y)=0$ but $f(x,0) \neq 0$. Can you compute $\frac{df(x,0)}{dx}$?